# HTTPS connection timeout

Tags: apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, https

Forgive me if this isn't the right place to ask, I'm trying to get HTTPS working on my Raspberry pi with Apache installed.

But when I try to connect to the domain the connection times out. HTTP does work though. Connecting to port 443 using my public IP doesn't work either.

Strangely enough, when I try to go to the https on the local ip it does work (https://192.168.x.x).

I have forwarded port 443, yet somewhere it's being blocked probably. When I scan my port locally with Nmap, it says the port is open. Although when I scan my public IP it states that the port is filtered.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that you're as stupid as I am, don't forward port 443 to two different IP's in your router. I don't even know why this is possible, must be a leftover from my OSCP days. I lost two days of my life to this.